# Set input values according to children of the parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

given series of DIVs w/unique ID as in:

```
<div id="2988">
    <div class="site">YaHoot.com</div>
    <div class="logo">/images/yahootLogo.jpg</div>
//[and so on]
    <input type="button" value="YaHoot" onclick="javascript:processMe('2988');" />
</div>

//[followed by bunches more divs repeating that structure]
```

I'm trying to code a click handler that can map a form's hidden fields with the contents of each of the child DIVs.

In other words, the form has a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="logo">
```

that should be valued with **/images/yahootLogo.jpg** when the given button is clicked.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use jQuery's context feature for this, like:

```
function processMe(id){
  var logo = $(".logo", "#"+id).text();

  $("input[name='logo']").val(logo);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to accomplish this by adding a click event to the buttons that follow the pattern.  In the example below I just used the [`:button` selector](http://api.jquery.com/button-selector/), but you would probably want to modify this to your needs, maybe you can piggy back on the `processMe()` function that it is already calling .

Also you may need to use [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) or [`prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) instead of [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) depending on the exact layout.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":button").click(function(){
        $("input[name='logo']").val($(this).prev(".logo").text());
    });
});
```

Example with [`prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":button").click(function(){
        $("input[name='logo']").val($(this).prevAll(".logo").text());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<div id="2988">
    <div class="site">YaHoot.com</div>
    <div class="logo">/images/yahootLogo.jpg</div>
//[and so on]
    <input type="button" value="YaHoot" onclick="javascript:processMe(this);" />
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

function processMe(id){
$(id).siblings().each(function(){
var class = $(this).attr('class');
$('input[name='+class+']').val($(this).val());
});
}
</script>

The above code will replace the values of all the div's with same parent in to the 
hidden fields with class name equal to the individual div's class name.
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
$(function() {
    $("#2988 div").each(function() {
        $(this).parent().append('<input type="hidden" name="'+$(this).attr("class")+'" value="'+$(this).text()+'" />');
    });   
});
```

Oh... as a sidenote, element IDs beginning with digits are technically invalid :)